# How to determine if a popover will be displayed as a popover or sheet in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, ipados, swiftui-environment, swiftui-sheet

In SwiftUI when a popover is displayed, it will display as either a popover or sheet depending on the device (iPad or iPhone) and window space available.

Is there a correct heuristic to check if the popover will be displayed as a popover or a sheet?

For example, on iPad, a popover will show as a sheet when multitasking and vertical or when horizontal at quarter-screen size.

Comment: [Human Interface Guides: Popovers](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/popovers/)

Comment: maybe `@Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass)`?

Comment: @ChrisR, unfortunately this doesn't work because `horizontalSizeClass` is constant on iPad across all multitasking layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is that I needed to pass down `horizontalSizeClass` from the parent view that was presenting the popover.
`.environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, horizontalSizeClass)` Without this, the child view was reading the `horizontalSizeClass` that was available to it (which is always compact within a popover).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my testing you CAN use `@Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass)` to find out:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var sizeClass
    
    @State private var showPopover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show PopOver") {
            showPopover = true
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
            Text(sizeClass == .regular ? "regular size" : "compact size")
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: ChrisR, which iPad and OS build is this? I get a popover on iPad half screen.

Comment: iPad 9th gen Simulator iOS 15.2 – when you get a popover does it a least say regular size?

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to check which simulator I was using again tomorrow. I was getting `.compact` and a popover at half-screen. I believe it's an iPad 9th gen as well.